# How to include a Percent Symbol in an xtable caption using Sweave in R

Tags: r, latex, sweave, xtable

I'm trying to use Sweave to generate a statistical report, and am trying to put a caption on an xtable, however if I include the percent symbol this breaks things.

Some example code

```
<<label=Analyte2_Results, results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
    print(xtable(result[[2]], caption=paste(levels(vardata$Analyte)[1],
                            " percent bias and precision estimates with 95 \% confidence intervals",sep="")),
            tabular.environment='longtable',
            latex.environments=c("center"), 
            floating=FALSE, 
            include.rownames=FALSE)
@
```

If I use % or \% then the Sweave process works but Latex doesn't, if I try \% then Sweave fails.  There doesn't seem to be an alternative way to specify a percent symbol in Latex

Is there a way to actually put a Percent symbol in the caption ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try "escaping" the "escape" operator, so that it survives Sweaving to make it to the LaTeX file (i.e., `\\%`). This is because in LaTeX the "%" needs an escape operator "\". For example, when I was naming some table rows and columns recently I had to use:

```
row.names(table.a) <- c("ARCH(1)", "~")
colnames(table.a) <- c("$\\omega$", "$\\alpha_{1}$", "Q(1)", "Q(12)")
```

Comment: I had tried that, and it didn't seem to work, but when I re-wrote the code it did work so go figure (or maybe there's an issue with using \\% in a 'paste'.